# Filter values according to the user chosen range in html sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working in an apps script that update a daily workflow calendar. I need:

1. to filter a range, that a user can choose from an html sidebar, which is below. The user choose the project that will correspond to a different range of the active sheet.
2. store the selected string with PropertiesService, but as this service store only strings I need to
3. transform the string in a sheet range (an array of arrays) and then
4. filter the range. The filter is: if the fist cell of the raw is checked (is true)  and the month of the second column correspond to the month stored in the variable month, than store the values in a variable result.

The sidebar is this one:

[image: sidebar]

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div class="section">
        <label> Scegli il progetto:
          <select name="chosenProject">
            <option value="" selected>Scegli...</option>
            <option value="values1">Breve-Processi</option>
            <option value="values2">Medio</option>
            <option value="values3">Lungo</option>
            
          </select>        
        </label>
      </div>
      
      <p id="output" class='loaded'></p>

      <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna il calendario" />

    </form>

    <script>      
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();      
      var chosenProject = document.querySelector('select[name="chosenProject"]').value;

      // Set the chosen project values and then update the calendar
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
        // Now that values are set, call updateCalendar
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
          document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'Calendario aggiornato!';
        }).updateCalendar();
      }).setValues(chosenProject);
    });
  });
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the gs code to store the values is this:

```
function setValues(chosenProject) {  
  var values;
  switch(chosenProject) {
    case "values1":
      values = srcSheet.getRange("A3:C" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
      break;
    case "values2":
      values = srcSheet.getRange("E3:G" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
      break;
    case "values3":
      values = srcSheet.getRange("I3:K" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
      break;
  }
  
  // Store the values array in script properties
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('chosenProject', JSON.stringify(values));  
}
```

I need to create a filter like this:

```
 var month = 10
 const filterValues = v => v.filter(([a, b]) => a === true && b.getMonth() == month).map(([, ...v]) => v);
```

But getting the v (values) from the setValues function.
How can I tranform the stored string with PropertiesService in an array of arrays and modify this filterValues function?

Comment: I don't understand you question.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Actually [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) understood correctly my question and thanks to him, I solved my problem. And, yes the first column is a checkbox so a boolean true or false, and the second column is a date. For the month variable, I'm aware that months start from 0, so November is 10. Now, for the month variable, I'll do the same as for the range: let the user choose the month. Now I understood how to do. Thank you!

Comment: @Emmanu Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `But getting the v (values) from the setValues function. How can I tranform the stored string with PropertiesService in an array of arrays and modify this filterValues function?`, if you want to use your function `filterValues` to the values stored with `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('chosenProject', JSON.stringify(values))`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This is your script.
  var month = 10;
  const filterValues = v => v.filter(([a, b]) => a === true && b.getMonth() == month).map(([, ...v]) => v);

  // I added the below script.
  var v = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('chosenProject');
  if (v != "") {
    var obj = JSON.parse(v);
    obj.forEach(r => r[1] = new Date(r[1]));
    var res = filterValues(obj);

    console.log(res); // You can see the result value in the log.

    return;
  }
  console.log("No value.");
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from PropertiesService stored by your script `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('chosenProject', JSON.stringify(values));`. And, the values are parsed and the values are used with `filterValues`.
- From your showing script, I guessed that the 1st column and 2nd column of `values` might be the boolean and the date object. In that case, when `values` are stored in PropertiesService as a string, it is required to convert the string to the date object when the values are retrieved from PropertiesService.
- By the way, in your script of `var month = 10; const filterValues = v => v.filter(([a, b]) => a === true && b.getMonth() == month).map(([, ...v]) => v);`, when the 1st and 2nd columns are "true" and "November", the values are returned. In the case of `getMonth()`, "January" is "0". Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)